# How can I change the color of the mean marker in plt.boxplot's showmeans?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've got a plot (below) with mean markers created with

```
for group in df.groups.unique():
    df_temp = df.loc[df["group"]==group]]
    ax = plt.plot(df_temp)

    plt.boxplot(df_temp, showmeans=True, meanprops={'color'=ax[0].get_color()})
```

How can I change the green triangle in the below figure to something else? I used `meanprops` above, but it doesn't seem to refer to what I thought it did.

[image: plot]

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/boxplot.html#sphx-glr-gallery-statistics-boxplot-py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As linked by Paul H, I updated my `meanprops` value to the following to change the color:

```
for group in df.groups.unique():
df_temp = df.loc[df["group"]==group]]
ax = plt.plot(df_temp)

plt.boxplot(df_temp, showmeans=True, 
    meanprops={'markerfacecolor': ax[0].get_color(), 'markeredgecolor': ax[0].get_color()})
```

The plot now looks like:

[image: plot]